# How can I subtract Integers in Groovy and retain leading zero's?

Tags: groovy

I have a code like :

```
def a = 2111 - 1112
//which calculates a as 999.
```

But in the above result i need `a` to be as `0999`, i.e i need the leading zeros in the `a`. How i can do this?

Comment: Recommended reading for padding strings: http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2009/09/groovy-goodness-padding-strings.html has details on `string.center(lengthAsInt, padString)`, `string.padRight(lengthAsInt, padString)` and `string.padLeft(lengthAsInt, padString)` - works as well without the padString parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like there should be a much Groovy-er solution, but this the best I could come up with:

```
Integer.metaClass.sub = {
    def padTo = Math.max(delegate.toString().length(), it.toString().length())
    return (delegate - it).toString().padLeft(padTo, '0')
}

println 2111.sub(1112)
```

I doubt you want to actually change the behavior of the "-" operator, but if you do, I think it'd be better if you changed String's metaClass.subtract instead and used "2111" - "1112"

Comment: Nice answer, but what does `delegate` does over here? and why does you have changed `max` function too? Confused.

Comment: delegate is the object that the method is being called on. I just used Math.max to determine how many 0s are needed to pad the number

Comment: You can also just write a method that takes two inputs of any type and returns the appropriate padded output.

Comment: @eric +1. posted a variation of yours with a default parameter and the spread operator :-)

Answer (score 4):

A Groovy-er solution might be:

```
Integer.metaClass.sub = { it, pad=[ "$it", "$delegate" ]*.length().max() ->
    "${delegate - it}".padLeft( pad, '0' )
}

println 2111.sub( 1112 )     // default padding
println 2111.sub( 1112, 10 ) // pad to 10 chars
```

which will print:

```
0999
0000000999
```

Comment: Yours is certainly Groovy-er :)

Comment: `pad=[ "$it", "$delegate" ]*.length().max()` in this code, how does you have called `max` function after calling the `length` function? How it works?

Comment: That code creates a list containing 2 strings. It then uses the spread operator to call length on all the items in the  so now, we have a list of lengths. Then it calls max on this list, and returns the biggest one

Answer (score 4):

This is a Java-y solution, but takes just 1 line to write, and it may be the "intended" usage:

```
    def a = 2111 - 1112
    def formatted = String.format("%04d", a)
    println "Number with leading zeroes: " + formatted //Prints 0999
```

The first argument to String includes the number of digits you want.

Comment: Perhaps it's more of a Unix-y solution, which java adopted for Java 5. I use these formats in Groovy often, and think it's the Groovy-est way.